# Out of memory exception when stsrtin a map view activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, out-of-memory

I have an application on the market which seems to be fine on my phone and some other phones I tested on. However I recently recived a crash report from a user whom says it crashed on starting the map activity. The exception is a out of memory exception on some bitmap.inflate operation related to the map view. In my tests my applicarion never passed 18 mb in ram and it never crashed on the map screen. I have a few map overlay layers but neither of them are heavy on graphics.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: what mobile does the crash reporter have? that would be interesting.

Comment: Is it possible the user had numerous copies of your map view activity running simultaneously? If so, the OOM error may not be hard to duplicate on your device, and the solution may be to update the manifest so you only have one copy of the activity loaded at a time.

Comment: @dpk: The activity flag is set to bring the already created activity to the front so it is not possible he had two activities

Comment: This seems to be a popular bug with an open bug report in google code page. (since 2009) :S

Answer (score 0):

You should try recycling the overlay bitmaps whenever the mapactivity closes and also whenever a particular overlay is removed/not needed. This occurs most often when working with bitmaps, the size incresaes and it crosses the VM heap size, and thus out of memory exception.
[Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle)

Comment: The problem is that I use drawables which are taken from the application's resources, and not bitmaps. If I try to recycle any of these drawable's bitmap, I won't be able to draw this drawable again (even if I reload it from the resources..).

Comment: According to user comment this happens right when the map screen is opened, so it's not related to not recycling bitmaps or what not.

Comment: If the map screen is opened multiple times then this can happen anytime when map screen is next opened. You should paste the entire stacktrace to let us know better about the crash.

Comment: The stack trace seems to be happening from the zoom controller of the map. at com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.createSnapshot(ZoomHelper.java:444)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating new Bitmap copies using your resources within a Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 config to keep memory use as low as possible and recycling them when not using them anymore?

A nice example of this can be found [here](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/288-android-how-to-load-bitmaps-rgb565)